# ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2

Tags: машинное-обучение, tensorflow, keras

я создаю нейросеть с связкой tensorflow/keras, однако возникает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/marik/PycharmProjects/food_detection/model.py", line 40, in <module>
   (trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)
 File "C:\Users\marik\PycharmProjects\food_detection\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 2197, in train_test_split
   train, test = next(cv.split(X=arrays[0], y=stratify))
 File "C:\Users\marik\PycharmProjects\food_detection\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 1793, in split
   y = check_array(y, ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
 File "C:\Users\marik\PycharmProjects\food_detection\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
   return f(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\marik\PycharmProjects\food_detection\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 659, in check_array
   raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Код:

```
import keras
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

# constans
INIT_LR = 1e-4
EPOCHS = 30
BS = 32
DIR = r"D:/food_dataset/images"

CATEGORIES = os.listdir(DIR)
print("[INFO] Loading images...")
data = []
labels = []
for category in CATEGORIES:
   path = os.path.join(DIR + "/", category)
   for img in os.listdir(path):
       img_path = os.path.join(path + "/", img)
       image = load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
       image = img_to_array(image)
       image = preprocess_input(image)
       data.append(image)
       labels.append(category)
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)

data = np.array(data, dtype="float32")
labels = np.array(labels)

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

aug = ImageDataGenerator(
   rotation_range=20,
   zoom_range=0.15,
   width_shift_range=0.2,
   height_shift_range=0.2,
   shear_range=0.15,
   horizontal_flip=True,
   fill_mode="nearest"
)

model = keras.Sequential(
   [
       keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)),
       Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
       MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
       Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
       MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
       BatchNormalization(),
       Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
       MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
       BatchNormalization(),
       Flatten(),
       Dense(256, activation="elu"),
       Dense(len(CATEGORIES), activation="softmax"),
   ]
)

print(model.summary())

opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=Input / EPOCHS)
model.complile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])

H = model.fit(
   aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
   steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
   validation_data=(testX, testY),
   validation_steps=len(testX) // BS,
   epochs=EPOCHS
)

model.save("food.h5")
```

Как можно исправить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, проблема здесь:

```
labels = to_categorical(labels)
```

И здесь:

```
train_test_split(..., stratify=labels, ...)
```

Полагаю, что `train_test_split` просто не понимает, как ему стратифицировать выборку по категориальной матрице. Для начала можете попробовать `train_test_split` без стратификации. Я точно не скажу, как это можно правильно переделать, чтобы получилась нормальная стратификация.